# Detect frame rate from a Windows process using Lua

Tags: windows, process, lua, scripting, frame-rate

Looking to retrieve the frame rate of a window from a windows process at a consistent interval to detect changes in performance.  Preferably by using Lua.  Is this possible?

Comment: Simply speaking, you want to make screenshots and compare them to each other to determine number of frames per second?

Comment: I suppose so, the idea is to use LUA to detect frame rates of windows applications similar to how a program like FRAPS works.